# OpenGL prevent rewriting uniforms between draw calls

Tags: c++, opengl

In the example below I have 2 meshes that use the same shader and I want to send different values
to each mesh the code below works but it seems unnecessary to send the data to the GPU every frame. Is there a way to send non-shader specific data to the GPU that can be used by the shader code and can by bound before draw calls?

I could just make a new shaders for every mesh I want to draw but this just seems like waste of memory.

```
glUseProgram(ShaderID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh1->VBO);
glBindVertexArray(mesh1->VAO);
glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)mvp1);
glUniform1fv(DataUniformID, 5, data1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh1->size);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh2->VBO);
glBindVertexArray(mesh2->VAO);
glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP_ID, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)mvp2);
glUniform1fv(DataUniformID, 5, data2);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh2->size);
```

Comment: Use a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) or a [Uniform Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object)

Comment: thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. I just got it working right now